# HTTP Node.js Java API

Tags: java, node.js, api, http, post

I am creating a Node.js Java backend. The Node.js middleware receives HTTP requests from an Android application and then relays it to the Java code. The reason for choosing this technologies is to create a highly scalable backend from scratch.

I want the Node.js api to receive the HTTP requests, pass it to the Java-side of the backend, the Java code does its calculations, sends back the result to the Node.js API and then finishes the process by sending the result back to the Android application.

I can receive and parse HTTP requests:

```js
var BodyParser = require('body-parser');
var Express = require('express');
var JavaClient = require('./NodeJavaBridge.js');

var JavaClientInstance = new JavaClient();
var app = Express();

/////  Receive message logic  \\\\\ 
app.use(BodyParser.json());

app.post('/', function (request, response) 
{
    var task = request.body;

    response.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
    
    var otherObject = { SomeData: 1234 };
    var json = JSON.stringify({
                    data: otherObject
                });
    
    response.end(json);
});

console.log("START --> Java Client Instance");
JavaClientInstance.run();

app.listen(8080); //to port on which the express server listen
console.log("Server listening on: " + 8080);
```

I can also send and receive data between Node.js and Java:

```js
var Util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var ChildProc = require('child_process');

var JavaClient = function () {
    var _self = this;
    
    // The child process object we get when we spawn the java process
    var _javaSpawn = null;
    
    // buffer for receiving messages in part and piecing them together later
    var _receiveBuffer = null;
    
    // The location of java and the - we're making these public because maybe
    // we want to change them in the user of this module.
    _self.javaPath = 'java';
    _self.jarPath = 'C:/Dev/Backend_Java.jar';
    _self.verbose = true;
    
    // list of events emitted - for informational purposes
    _self.events = [
        'spawn', 'message', 'exception', 'unknown', 'sent', 'java_error',

        // Response messages that then become events themselves
        'Error', 'Hello', 'Info'
    ];
    
    /**
     * Attach our own event handler to reply to the hello message.
     * This is just a convenience part of the protocol so that clients don't have to do it.
     * Also connects if connection data was supplied.
     */
    _self.on('Hello', function () {
        _self.sendHello();
    });
    
    /**
     * Executes the java process to begin sending and receiving communication
     */
    _self.run = function () {
        // Invoke the process
        _javaSpawn = ChildProc.spawn(_self.javaPath, ['-jar', _self.jarPath]);
        
        // Wire up events
        _javaSpawn.stdout.on('data', onData);
        _javaSpawn.stderr.on('data', onJavaError);
        _javaSpawn.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log("The java program exited with code " + code + ".");            
        });
        
        // Emit our own event to indicate to others that we have spawned
        _self.emit('spawn', _javaSpawn);
    }
    
    // sends the hello request message
    _self.sendHello = function () {
        sendMessage(
            {
                messageName : 'Hello',
                version     : '1.1'
            });
    }
    
    // sends a message that will be echoed back as an Info message
    _self.sendEcho = function (message) {
        sendMessage(
            {
                messageName : "Echo",
                message     : message
            });
    }
    
    // sends a message telling the java app to exit
    _self.sendGoodbye = function () {
        sendMessage(
            {
                "messageName" : "Goodbye"
            });
    }
    
    /**
     * Sends a message object as a JSON encoded string to the java application for processing.
     */
    function sendMessage(aMsg) 
    {
        // convert to json and prepare buffer
        var aJsonString = JSON.stringify(aMsg);
        var lByteLength = Buffer.byteLength(aJsonString);
        var lMsgBuffer = new Buffer(4 + lByteLength);
        
        // Write 4-byte length, followed by json, to buffer
        lMsgBuffer.writeUInt32BE(lByteLength, 0);
        lMsgBuffer.write(aJsonString, 4, aJsonString.length, 'utf8');
        
        // send buffer to standard input on the java application
        _javaSpawn.stdin.write(lMsgBuffer);
        
        _self.emit('sent', aMsg);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive data over standard input
     */
    function onData(data) 
    {
        
        // Attach or extend receive buffer
        _receiveBuffer = (null == _receiveBuffer) ? data : Buffer.concat([_receiveBuffer, data]);
        
        // Pop all messages until the buffer is exhausted
        while (null != _receiveBuffer && _receiveBuffer.length > 3) 
        {
            var size = _receiveBuffer.readInt32BE(0);
            
            // Early exit processing if we don't have enough data yet
            if ((size + 4) > _receiveBuffer.length) 
            {
                break;
            }
            
            // Pull out the message
            var json = _receiveBuffer.toString('utf8', 4, (size + 4));
            
            // Resize the receive buffer
            _receiveBuffer = ((size + 4) == _receiveBuffer.length) ? null : _receiveBuffer.slice((size + 4));
            
            // Parse the message as a JSON object
            try 
            {
                var msgObj = JSON.parse(json);
                
                // emit the generic message received event
                _self.emit('message', msgObj);
                
                // emit an object-type specific event
                if ((typeof msgObj.messageName) == 'undefined') 
                {
                    _self.emit('unknown', msgObj);
                }
                else 
                {
                    _self.emit(msgObj.messageName, msgObj);
                }
            }
            catch (ex) 
            {
                _self.emit('exception', ex);
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive error output from the java process
     */
    function onJavaError(data) 
    {
        _self.emit('java_error', data.toString());
    }
}

// Make our JavaClient class an EventEmitter
Util.inherits(JavaClient, EventEmitter);

// export our class
module.exports = JavaClient;
```

My problem: How do I let the POST request send a request to my JavaClient instance, wait for a response and then send it back to origin (Android app).

Here is an example of how I am trying to get the logic working:

```js
var client = require('./JavaClient');

var instance = new client();

instance.on('message', function(msg) {
  console.log('Received a message...');
  console.log(msg);
});

instance.on('sent', function(msg) {
  console.log('Sent a message...');
  console.log(msg);
});

instance.on('Info', function(msg) {
  console.log("Received info");
  console.log(msg.message);
});

(function() {
  // Start it up (Hello exchanges happen)
  instance.run();

  // Receive acknowledgement of hello
  instance.once('Info', function() {
    // Try echoing something
    instance.sendEcho("ECHO!");
  });

})();
```

If I should make something more clear please let me know (it's really late and I assume that my writing capabilities is taking a dive). I would appreciate any answer/suggestion/thisisabadidea type of comments.

Thanks!

Comment: Is the Java part time consuming ? You will have to consider the gateway timeout if rest APIs are into business.

Comment: @PhagunBaya yes, there is a chance that I can be be time consuming. If this is going to be a problem, what would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest to track the process in some in-memory cache. Along with this you will need to send back the response to this API with a track id and client will poll some API to get back status of the process. Or you can use socket.io to send back the final response to client using the socket connection.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var Util = require('util');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var ChildProc = require('child_process');

var JavaClient = function () {
    var _self = this;
    
    // The child process object we get when we spawn the java process
    var _javaSpawn = null;
    
    // buffer for receiving messages in part and piecing them together later
    var _receiveBuffer = null;
    
    // The location of java and the - we're making these public because maybe
    // we want to change them in the user of this module.
    _self.javaPath = 'java';
    _self.jarPath = 'C:/Dev/Backend_Java.jar';
    _self.verbose = true;
    
    // list of events emitted - for informational purposes
    _self.events = [
        'spawn', 'message', 'exception', 'unknown', 'sent', 'java_error',

        // Response messages that then become events themselves
        'Error', 'Hello', 'Info'
    ];
    
    /**
     * Attach our own event handler to reply to the hello message.
     * This is just a convenience part of the protocol so that clients don't have to do it.
     * Also connects if connection data was supplied.
     */
    _self.on('Hello', function () {
        _self.sendHello();
    });
    
    /**
     * Executes the java process to begin sending and receiving communication
     */
    _self.run = function () {
        // Invoke the process
        _javaSpawn = ChildProc.spawn(_self.javaPath, ['-jar', _self.jarPath]);
        
        // Wire up events
        _javaSpawn.stdout.on('data', onData);
        _javaSpawn.stderr.on('data', onJavaError);
        _javaSpawn.on('exit', function (code) {
            console.log("The java program exited with code " + code + ".");            
        });
        
        // Emit our own event to indicate to others that we have spawned
        _self.emit('spawn', _javaSpawn);
    }
    
    // sends the hello request message
    _self.sendHello = function () {
        sendMessage(
            {
                messageName : 'Hello',
                version     : '1.1'
            });
    }
    
    // sends a message that will be echoed back as an Info message
    _self.sendEcho = function (message) {
        sendMessage(
            {
                messageName : "Echo",
                message     : message
            });
    }
    
    // sends a message telling the java app to exit
    _self.sendGoodbye = function () {
        sendMessage(
            {
                "messageName" : "Goodbye"
            });
    }
    
    /**
     * Sends a message object as a JSON encoded string to the java application for processing.
     */
    function sendMessage(aMsg) 
    {
        // convert to json and prepare buffer
        var aJsonString = JSON.stringify(aMsg);
        var lByteLength = Buffer.byteLength(aJsonString);
        var lMsgBuffer = new Buffer(4 + lByteLength);
        
        // Write 4-byte length, followed by json, to buffer
        lMsgBuffer.writeUInt32BE(lByteLength, 0);
        lMsgBuffer.write(aJsonString, 4, aJsonString.length, 'utf8');
        
        // send buffer to standard input on the java application
        _javaSpawn.stdin.write(lMsgBuffer);
        
        _self.emit('sent', aMsg);
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive data over standard input
     */
    function onData(data) 
    {
        
        // Attach or extend receive buffer
        _receiveBuffer = (null == _receiveBuffer) ? data : Buffer.concat([_receiveBuffer, data]);
        
        // Pop all messages until the buffer is exhausted
        while (null != _receiveBuffer && _receiveBuffer.length > 3) 
        {
            var size = _receiveBuffer.readInt32BE(0);
            
            // Early exit processing if we don't have enough data yet
            if ((size + 4) > _receiveBuffer.length) 
            {
                break;
            }
            
            // Pull out the message
            var json = _receiveBuffer.toString('utf8', 4, (size + 4));
            
            // Resize the receive buffer
            _receiveBuffer = ((size + 4) == _receiveBuffer.length) ? null : _receiveBuffer.slice((size + 4));
            
            // Parse the message as a JSON object
            try 
            {
                var msgObj = JSON.parse(json);
                
                // emit the generic message received event
                _self.emit('message', msgObj);
                
                // emit an object-type specific event
                if ((typeof msgObj.messageName) == 'undefined') 
                {
                    _self.emit('unknown', msgObj);
                }
                else 
                {
                    _self.emit(msgObj.messageName, msgObj);
                }
            }
            catch (ex) 
            {
                _self.emit('exception', ex);
            }
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Receive error output from the java process
     */
    function onJavaError(data) 
    {
        _self.emit('java_error', data.toString());
    }
}

// Make our JavaClient class an EventEmitter
Util.inherits(JavaClient, EventEmitter);

// export our class
module.exports = JavaClient;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var client = require('./JavaClient');

var instance = new client();

instance.on('message', function(msg) {
  console.log('Received a message...');
  console.log(msg);
});

instance.on('sent', function(msg) {
  console.log('Sent a message...');
  console.log(msg);
});

instance.on('Info', function(msg) {
  console.log("Received info");
  console.log(msg.message);
});

(function() {
  // Start it up (Hello exchanges happen)
  instance.run();

  // Receive acknowledgement of hello
  instance.once('Info', function() {
    // Try echoing something
    instance.sendEcho("ECHO!");
  });

})();
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written