# Connecting Discord node.js bot to an external Java client

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a bot for my discord server that I wrote in Node.js using discord.js; Its hosted 24/7.
I am writing a client in Java that I want to connect to the bot so I can pull members from my server and display them in my application.
Kind of like how you'd embed a twitter feed on a webpage.

How would i go about doing that without connecting a second bot to my server.
I have my bot token if that helps?

Comment: Open some port on the nodejs server and connect to that with Java. Maybe something like http://socket.io or just simple http requests

Comment: I'm using glitch.com to write my bot and uptimerobot.com to keep it alive. And my bot is listening on port 3000. I'll be able to connect to those with Java?

Comment: I think you need your own server for this.

Comment: I couldn't find anything on the subject. I've added socket.io to my bot and right now im trying the http requests in java.

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36923974/http-node-js-java-api but i'm not sure if its correct

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to do an API in node that your java application will request.

For example, you will set up a server listening on port 3000. If a request is sent to your bot on this port (for example `your-ip:3000/members`) you will respond with a list of members.

You will have to set up the bot and (saying you're using `http`) the `http` server in the same app.

Create a server, log your bot with your token:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const config = require("./config.json");

const http = require('http');

const hostname = '127.0.0.1';
const port = 3000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  respondToRequest(req, res);
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});


// client action
client.on("message", respondToMessage);
client.login(config.token);
console.log("bot is starting");
```

And then handle the events you want to handle. 
Here is an example I did to handle a gitlab request

```js
function respondToRequest (request, response){
  let res = "";
  if ("x-gitlab-event" in request["headers"]){ // check if the request is correct
    let body = "";
    request.on('data', function(chunk){ // read the request
      body += chunk;
    });
    request.on('end', function(){
      try {
    createEmbedMessage(request, JSON.parse(body));
    res = "Hook ok\n"; // here is the response sent to gitlab
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}); 
    response.end(res);
      } catch (e){
    console.log("JSON invalid: ", e);
    response.writeHead(400, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}); 
    response.end("NO\n");
      }
    });
  } else {
    res = "link to git\n";
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"}); 
    response.end(res);
  }
}
```

It check if the request is correct (to avoid answering to any type of request), then it read the body request and use it to write an embed message in Discord. Then it respond to the request with a simple 'Hook ok' message.
Instead of responding with 'Hook ok', you'll want to get the list of member you want (general or specific) and then sent it as an answer, formatting in JSON for example.